# Изменение цвета границы после события нажатия

Tags: html, css3

как изменить цвет `input border :color` после события нажатия?

```html
<input type="text"class="Input">
```

Comment: отредактируйте и уточните свой вопрос, что означает "после нажатии"

Comment: @Tiarait я хочу чтобы после нажатии инпута цвет черный рамки изменилось но всё таки спасибо))

Comment: @WhiteMoon какого ещё нажатия? Уточняйте, при `:active`? Или как?

Comment: просто хочу убрать стандартный черный  цвет рамки инпута  не знаю after или что-то еще после нажатии

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию у инпутов есть outline, сам селектор при фокусе называется focus. Советую изменить стандартный outline на border, т.к. с ним проще работать

```html
<style>
input {
        outline: none;
        border: 1px solid black;
 }
input:focus {
        outline: red;
        border-color: red;
 }
</style>
```